# Delete All from Observable - Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I would like to delete everything that is in an Observable. So far I have done this :

However this implies that if I have 500 elements in my Observable, I would be doing 500 http calls which in a performance point of view is not reliable.

Could you tell me if there is an easier way to delete all the entries in my Observable ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: The moment you needed to be able to perform changes in bulk, you should be looking to handle that in the backend APIs. You certainly don't want to issue a delete for every item that exists, there are plenty of more efficient ways to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a job for the backend. What you have there? Backend should have a separate endpoint for `delete all` or take some parameters on the current endpoint to do so.

Comment: Actually I don't have a backend, I am using json-server. Is there a way to delete everything in the json-server file without having to do multiple api calls ?

Comment: Seems like the API is configurable. Maybe `this.http.delete(this.apiURL)` https://github.com/typicode/json-server#getting-started

Comment: I tried with this.http.delete(this.apiURL) but it gives me a 404 error

Comment: Like I said - configure it too 

Comment: Oh ok I didn't get what you were saying at first

Answer (score 0):

whenever you don't need to using an observable that you have subscribed to it, easily you can unsubscribe it.
About Http requests, they will cancel. But be sure about side effects of you Api call on your backend. For Example maybe they don't care about your cancellation.